# Display text on the right of the div tag

Tags: html, css

What i want to do is the text that is bold i want to show it up here
[image]
And my code is

```
    img{
        margin-left:10px;
    }
```

html

```
<div id="wrap">
    <img src="bg.jpg" />
    <b class="name">WaqasTahir</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) your image to the left:

```
#userimg{
    margin-left:10px;
    float: left;
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Z9K5/)**

Comment: can i center the text i mean i want it in center up and down space equal but i have tried margin and padding nothing worked

Comment: @Waqas Vertical-align will not work, you need to use margin. The reason it did not work is because `.name` is set to `display: inline;` margin will only work on elements with `display: block;` or `inline-block`

Comment: @Waqas Or another (probably better) way to do it is to set `line-height` on `.name` to the same height as `#wrap`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Z9K5/1/